# Why is Google asking "Did you mean..." when it's the same word?

Tags: google-search, search

So Google comes up with this when there is no difference in the spelling at all

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's a joke. It keeps referring you to 'Recursion' recursively.

Comment: Oh my...I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

It's just Google, trying to be funny

[image]